# What is the fastest way to load IPFS content in the Brave browser?

Tags: performance, ipfs

My site communicates with IPFS files and I need to figure out which way the files will be downloaded faster from the user

1. Take IPFS cids directly (example: ipfs://QmXoypizjW3WknFiJnKLwHCnL72vedxjQkDDP1mXWo6uc)
2. Take IPFS cids via gateway aggregators (e.g. ipfs.io, cloudflare-ipfs.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the IPFS Gateway can perform way better than a local node. However your speed may vary from where you live, so be sure to check from https://ipfs.github.io/public-gateway-checker/ for the fastest gateway for you. and using it will improve your speed.